# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-navigationview

### I don't have this code in MainActivity.java, I have it in one called Login.java

I have this error in the Logcat:

> ```
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Menu
> com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.getMenu()' on a null object reference
>     at com.store.Credenciales.Login.addMenuItemLogOut(Login.java:93)
> ```

My code in Login.java:93 is this function:

```
private void addMenuItemLogOut(){
    NavigationView navigationView= (NavigationView) findViewById(nav_view);
    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu(); //Line 93
    menu.findItem(R.id.nav_signin).setVisible(false);
    menu.findItem(R.id.nav_send).setVisible(true);
}
```

And command to bring the function higher, when a user entered correct username and password

```
if(isLogin){
    addMenuItemLogOut(); //Here
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle =  new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("user_id", userd);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: @0X0nosugar Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`NullPointerException`** is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value.

You should use  **[getHeaderView (int index)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView#getheaderview)** instead of **<s>getMenu()</s>** .

> Gets the header view at the specified position.

Try with

```
 NavigationView navigationView       = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 View header         = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_signin).setVisible(false);
 navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_send).setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Now i have this: 

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView.getHeaderView(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: you should use `findViewById(R.id.your_id)` . Check your id `nav_view` exists in xml?

Comment: Yes, it exists in activity_main.xml

Comment: I don't have this code in MainActivity.java, I have it in one called Login.java

Comment: @snow915 Your `NavigationView` belongs from which Activity?

Comment: It's in Login.java

Comment: `Yes, it exists in activity_main.xml `  &  `I don't have this code in MainActivity.java`. Seems like your NavigationView coming from MainActivity. If your NavigationView coming from from MainActivity(layout will activity_main) then write your code MainActivity section else Login Activity section.